# Trying to update a field of a single object whilst also pushing to an array nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Within this post function i am trying to award a badge and then after the badge has been awarded within an array to the usermodel i am trying to update a separate field in the user doc which i have named as points, the udoc.total points currently works however after the call is finished the users total points do not update and stay as 0 
Usermodel schema -

```
var schema = new Schema({
    email : {type:String, require:true},
    username: {type:String, require:true},
    password:{type:String, require:true},
    creation_dt:{type:Date, require:true},
    diabeticType:{type:String, require:true},
    badges: [Badges],
    totalPoints: {type:Number, require:true},
    glucoseReading : [
        {
            bloodGlucoseLevel : {
                type : String,
                required : "Required"
            },
            dosageTime : {
                type : String,
            },
            unitsOfInsulinForFood : {
                type : String,
            },
            correctionDose : {
                type : String,
            },

            creation_dt :{
                type : String,
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

and then this is the post command where the badge is added to the users profile however the total points do not update

```
router.post("/:id/badge/:bid", function (req, res){{'useFindAndModify', false}
  Badgemodel.findById(req.params.bid).then(doc => {
    if(!doc) 
    { 
        return res.status(404).end();
    }
    else
    {
        var awardBadge = doc;
        Usermodel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
            {$push : {badges : awardBadge}},

            {safe : true, upsert: true}).then(udoc =>{
                if(!doc) 
                { 
                    return res.status(404).end();
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log(udoc);
                    console.log(udoc.totalPoints);
                    udoc.totalPoints = udoc.totalPoints + awardBadge.value;
                    console.log(udoc.totalPoints);
                    return res.status(200).end();

                }
            })
    }
})

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your User Schema.
You are trying to reference a array of documents of the `Badges` collection in your User Schema definition at `badges: [Badges],`.

But when you reference a doc from an other collection in mongoose the syntax is different.
Checkout the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

The schema should look like this:

```js
badges: [{
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: "UserModel" // or whatever the Model name is
}]
```

see also
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schematype.html#schematype_SchemaType-ref

Comment: Hi i have defined the badge schema as a different model, im not having an issue with assigning the badges to the users the issue is more not being able to send the updated total points to save to the users info i think.

Answer (score 0):

Answer- I was storing the value for total points into a variable and this variable was not being sent back to the users info. I updated code by adding in another findbyidandupdate and included the $set function to update the users total points to the value of the variable udoc.total points.

router.post("/:id/badge/:bid", function (req, res){{'useFindAndModify', false}
  Badgemodel.findById(req.params.bid).then(doc => {
    if(!doc) 
    { 
        return res.status(404).end();
    }
    else
    {
        var awardBadge = doc;
        Usermodel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
            {$push : {badges : awardBadge}},

```
        {safe : true, upsert: true}).then(udoc =>{
            if(!doc) 
            { 
                return res.status(404).end();
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(udoc);
                console.log(udoc.totalPoints);
                udoc.totalPoints = udoc.totalPoints + awardBadge.value;
                Usermodel.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {$set: {totalPoints : udoc.totalPoints} }).then(doc => {
                    if(!doc) 
                    { 
                        return res.status(404).end();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        return res.status(200).end();
                        res.send(doc);

                    }
                })   
                console.log(udoc.totalPoints);
                return res.status(200).end();
                res.send(doc);

            }
        })
}
```

})

})